# scrollable table header jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing scrollable table header, table is generated using php
I use a following code for make scroll, when I run it, this code just doesn't work:
here is table generation code 
also I tried to refere to class header, that didn't work too

```
echo "<table class=\"container\"><tr><td><table class=\"mystyle\"><tr><td class=\"header\"></td>";


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".container").find(".mystyle").scrollTop();
     });                
</script>
```

here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong depends on what you really want to do.

Comment: Could you post more details (some html for example) ?

Comment: echo "<table class=\"container\"><tr><td><table class=\"mystyle\"><tr><td class=\"header\"></td>"; Here's php code generate table, I would like to make header scroll

Comment: Do not post the code in comments. Edit your question and put your code in. Also add more details, like *what exactly does not work, what should happen when you ran the script, what's happening when you ran this script...*. It's quite impossible to answer the question in this form.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/ something llke this?